# Availability statut in product-list not showing Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

when I list all products from a category of my web the products show the availability statut. However, if I choose an option to filter results or I click in the next page button to see other products, this label disappears.

I don't know why it's happen? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have this behavior properly coded in the global.js in the 
display function